# How to change the link title for the Facebook "like" button and Google?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, google-search

When someone clicks on the "like" button on my website with their Facebook, it displays "(Name) likes Home - Michael Fucking Pitluk" on their Facebook pages' like feed.

Also, when searching on google for "Michael Pitluk", my website link shows up as "Michael Fucking Pitluk".

AFAIK, no where in my website's current coding do I say this.  How do I change it? Why is it showing up?

I did previously have a wordpress site where I did write this.  But, I took that down.  How is it still showing up?

Thanks.

Website: http://michaelpitluk.com

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel michaelpitluk.com

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fmichaelpitluk.com  I see some errors here

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel What do those errors mean and how can I fix them?

Comment: Come on, this is Q&A site, not I-am-too-lazy-to-reads-docs site. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects/

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel Apologies.  I'm extremely new to this.  I wouldn't have even know where to begin looking, let alone understand it. Thanks though.

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel Can you please point to where the general problem is so I can read about that specifically, for now? Appreciate it.

Comment: The problem is you should add meta tags to your headers with names and vaules as specified in FB debugger above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of Michael Szyndel, I was able to fix my problem.

I had no idea what meta tags were or how they related to the facebook like button until I read  these articles:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects/ 
http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-meta-tags

The solution was rather simple.  I just had to add the following to my html head element:

```
        <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
        <meta property="og:url" content="http://michaelpitluk.com"/>
        <meta property="og:title" content="Michael Pitluk - Singer/Songwriter"/>
        <meta property="og:image" content="http://michaelpitluk.com/img/looking-up-michael-pitluk.png"/>
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="Michael Pitluk - Singer/Songwriter"/>
        <meta property="og:description" content="Michael Pitluk is a singer/songwriter, guitarist, recording engineer, producer, and studio owner in Southern California."/>
```